# Doctrine2 many-to-many returns one record in join

Tags: doctrine-orm

There are 2 tables - one has a list of works - another a list of genres, joined in many-to-many. When I run the query, it returns only one genre per work. I need for it to return all works with all corresponding genres.

```
$QB->select("Works","Works, Genres")
                ->from($repo), 'Works')
                ->innerJoin("Works.Genres","Genres");
```

I tried it with both `leftJoin` and `innerJoin`

Also I further add a `Where` condition to search by genre and the same situation appears - if there are more than 1 genre to search by it returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding `groupBy` statement.

```
$QB->addGroupBy('Genres');
```

Now it returns all the related genres for the work.